# Proper flutter/dart formatting

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I am working in some flutter code. The code stacks closing braces on the same line. In addition, when I run "Format Document" in VSCode, it also stacks the braces on a single line.

Like this (see last line)...

```
return Container(
    width: 200,
    child: CupertinoTextField(
        maxLength: 10,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0))),
        style: accentTextStyle,
        placeholder: "NAME",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
        controller: _textController,
        onChanged: (s) {
          navigation.update();
          if (s == '') {
            program.name = 'UNNAMED${navigation.programsCounter}';
            return;
          }
          program.name = s.toUpperCase();
        }));
```

But in the flutter docs and example code, all of the examples use the follow format (where braces are on separate lines).

```
return Container(
  width: 200,
  child: CupertinoTextField(
    maxLength: 10,
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
    focusNode: focusNode,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0))),
    style: accentTextStyle,
    placeholder: "NAME",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
    controller: _textController,
    onChanged: (s) {
      navigation.update();
      if (s == '') {
        program.name = 'UNNAMED${navigation.programsCounter}';
        return;
      }
      program.name = s.toUpperCase();
    }
  )
);
```

Which is the proper format? Also, does "Format Document" use the dart extension to get the proper format?

Comment: Ok, you can look at the editing part at the end of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64543605/10659482

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use comma(,) at the end of the braces. Then the 'Format Document' will separate the lines for each brace. Try this:

```
return Container(
 width: 200,
 child: CupertinoTextField(
    maxLength: 10,
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
    focusNode: focusNode,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0))),
    style: accentTextStyle,
    placeholder: "NAME",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
    controller: _textController,
    onChanged: (s) {
      navigation.update();
      if (s == '') {
        program.name = 'UNNAMED${navigation.programsCounter}';
        return;
      }
      program.name = s.toUpperCase();
    },
   ),
  );
```

**Edit:**

Ok, you are looking for the proper method. As mentioned in the [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting), you should use trailing commas.

> To get good automatic formatting, we recommend you adopt the optional trailing commas.

Comment: You can add rules on `analysis_options.yaml` for auto adding trailing comas.

`require_trailing_commas: true`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the same indentation by adding `commas` between the braces and hit the indentation button:

- VS Code: `alt + shift + f`
- Android Studio: `ctrl + alt + l`

Works perfectly fine for me :)

Adding Commas like:

```
onChanged: (s) {
          navigation.update();
          if (s == '') {
            program.name = 'UNNAMED${navigation.programsCounter}';
            return;
          }
          program.name = s.toUpperCase();
        },),);
```

After indentaion:

```
    onChanged: (s) {
      navigation.update();
      if (s == '') {
        program.name = 'UNNAMED${navigation.programsCounter}';
        return;
      }
      program.name = s.toUpperCase();
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though.

Comment: Sir, there is no proper format. Its upto you whichever suits you. I just added how to achieve a well formatted code. P.S I didn't hear from any Flutter engineer about formats. They recommended the solution I shared with you :)
Cheers, Good day :)

Comment: No there is a correct format, it is the one specified by the dartfmt project which is a an opinionated formatter. So I am curious if VSCode is using this or not, and which format matches.

Comment: I think it is .dart extension maybe, but if you add `commas` it will format them in proper fashion ending with `//Container` like comments for more clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, @Akif's answer did it for me. Make sure you have a comma at the end of your closing ) and the formatter will work as expected.

Without commas at the end your formatter will do this:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My First App'),
    ))));
```

If you add the commas at the end the results will look like this:

```
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My First App'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

So i guess it's good practice to always add a comma even if there's only 1 element for formatting purposes.